# Socket recv() returns immediately

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm writing a program where, upon a save of a new object in the Django database I need to connect to a another server to send and receive some data. I've extended the save function in my model with this functionality, but I'm seeing some unexpected behaviour. Specifically, the socket recv immediately returns, which is unexpected for me, as I created a blocking socket instead of a non-blocking socket.
I expected my code to wait for data on the recv call. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

My save function looks as follows:

```python
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.logger.info('Attempting save!')
    super(SpaDevice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.operation == 3 or self.operation == 4:
        pass
        # handle checkin to service
    elif self.operation == 8:
        # handle registration
        # sock = socket.create_connection(('localhost', 45309), timeout=60)
        sock = socket.create_connection(('localhost', 45309))

        data = {"unique_id": self.dev_id, "request_type": 'checkin'}
        try:
            self.logger.info('Attempting to register {0}'.format(self.dev_id))
            bytes_send = sock.send(json.dumps(data).encode())
            if bytes_send > 0:
                while True:
                    data = sock.recv(1024)
                    if data == b'':
                        # Empty data? WhY? Try again
                        continue
                    elif data is None:
                        # Other side closed the connection on us, how rude!
                        self.logger.error('Other side closed connection, how rude')
                        break
                    else:
                        self.logger.info('received: {0}'.format(data.decode()))
                        break

            else:
                self.logger.error('Failed to send data to gcmgw')
        finally:
            sock.close()
```

I don't understand why this happens; could someone explain this behavior!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out what was happening. The server closed the connection on me, causing the recv call to return immediately. It doesn't return None in that case, but an empty bytes object.

A wireshark trace quickly made that clear.